# Issue with Spark SQL to Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm getting error in the following code:

> txn = spark.sql('select * from temporary view').toPandas()

I got Py4JavaError: An error occurred while calling o420.collectToPython.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure.

Please help!